# What are the best documentation sites specific to ASP.Net MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Now that the MVC 2 framework has been out for a while, I'm finding it very difficult to find documentation & answers specific to MVC2.

What are some good sites specific to MVC2?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good sample sites you could look at:

http://nerddinner.codeplex.com and http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

And the MSDN documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff520618.aspx which also has a link to other samples.

Comment: That sort of points out the problem - the nerddinner link is for 1.0, NOT 2 - and the msdn link talk about MVC2, but links to the MVC1 namespace documentation!

Comment: Nerddinner is MVC2 if you download source code - http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets
Also samples on MSDN are MVC2 - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetmvcsamples

Comment: You might want to opt in for a regular book - Professional ASP.Net MVC2 - http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/0470643188/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1276547918&sr=8-1

Answer (score 0):

[Scott Gu's blog is invaluable.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) Not just for MVC2, but all things IIS.

[Asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos) has some material.

Otherwise you are mostly right, the documentation availability sucks.  Especially if you are looking MVC2 specifically.